# Bounding box offset of fabricjs path

Tags: javascript, path, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a shape by using a fabric.Path, and I would like to be able to rotate it around its center. Problem is, that the bounding box is offset, and the actual shape dances around its center:

[image]

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
this.canvas.clear();

var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
width: 20,
            height: 20,
            fill: '#35a2da',
left: 410,
top: 350,
angle: 90
});


var path = new fabric.Path(
  "M 200 175 A 25 25 0 1 0 217.678 217.678",
        {
        fill : '',
        stroke : '#35a2da',
        strokeWidth : 7,
        left: 200, 
        top:200
    });

var rotate = new fabric.Group([path, triangle], {left:200, top:200});

this.canvas.add(rotate);
```

The code above can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HFHcN/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you fix the dimensions of the `fabric.Path` object based on the SVG arc that you're drawing, *and* fix the dimensions of the `fabric.Group` to those same dimensions, you should be able to get the shape to be perfectly centered.

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natchiketa/LFYMG/)

## Reasons for explicity sizing

### `fabric.Path`

The reason you want to explicitly set the width and height of the `fabric.Path` is because otherwise the default size will include the additional size from the stroke of the arc.

### `fabric.Group`

The reason to explicitly set the size of the `fabric.Group` is because with the `fabric.Triangle` positioned at the start of the arc, the bounds will extend outside of that circle on which you want to be perfectly centered.

## How to dynamically calculate the rotate icon SVG path

I wrote this function that returns an object with the points you'll need to render the SVG arc, given the radius:

```js
function rotatePoints(radius) {
    // Get 45 degrees in radians
    var angle = Math.PI / 4;
    return {
        radius: radius,
        startPos: {
            x: radius,
            y: 0
        },
        endPos: {
            x: radius + (radius * Math.cos(angle)),
            y: radius + (radius * Math.sin(angle))
        }
    }
}
```

For example, given a radius of 30, you could build the SVG path like this:

```js
var pathPts = rotatePoints(30);
var pathSVG = [
    'M', pathPts.startPos.x, pathPts.startPos.y,
    'A', pathPts.radius, pathPts.radius,
    0, 1, 0,
    pathPts.endPos.x, pathPts.endPos.y
];    
pathSVG.join(' ') // result: "M 30 0 A 30 30 0 1 0 51.21320343559643 51.21320343559643"
```

## Canvas Coordinates vs. Group Coordinates

Keep in mind that once you add the `Path` and `Triangle` to the `Group`, if you want to set the position of either, the coordinates are relative to the bounds of the `Group`, not the whole canvas (see the fiddle for an example of how their positions are adjusted being added to the `Group`.